# How to send EventArgs when using multiple parameters through InvokeCommandAction?

Tags: c#, wpf, attachedbehaviors

I would like to use `InvokeCommandAction` to send `MouseButtonEventArgs.ChangedButton` and a parameter of my choice.

I can send the arg value using `TriggerParameterPath`.

I can send multiple parameters using a `MultiBinding` along with a `IMultiValueConverter`.

How can I do both?

Comment: It might be simpler just to use code-behind for this.  Write an event handler.  In the event handler take what event data your need, get the DataContext as your viewmodel type and manually invoke the command.  I like the interactivity stuff but often it seems a bit too verbose for my needs

Comment: That’s what I’m currently doing. I’d like to know if this is possible though. I’ll download the source tomorrow and step through and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Newer Prism versions use the [*Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf) package for the interactivity types, so the `InvokeCommandAction` type from there will be used in the following. For older versions using the legacy `System.Windows.Interactivity` types, the same is applicable.

If you inspect the code for the [`InvokeCommandAction`](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors/InvokeCommandAction.cs) type in the [`Invoke(object parameter)` method](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/blob/6c12334a7309811be225de9d19e24f678e74ae08/src/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors/InvokeCommandAction.cs#L110), you can see that either the `CommandParameter` or the event arguments can be passed and if both are specified, the `CommandParameter` takes precedence. Consequently, by design this is not possible.

What you can do is create your own implementation of the `InvokeCommanAction`. Unfortunately, the type is marked `sealed` for some reason, so you are left to copy the implementation and adapt it.

The following serves as an example that you can vary to fit your requirements. Create a type that can hold both the event arguments and the command parameter.

```
public class CompositeCommandParameter
{
   public CompositeCommandParameter(EventArgs eventArgs, object parameter)
   {
      EventArgs = eventArgs;
      Parameter = parameter;
   }

   public EventArgs EventArgs { get; }

   public object Parameter { get; }
}
```

Copy the original code of the `InvokeCommandAction` and adapt the `Invoke` method like this.

```
protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
{
   if (AssociatedObject != null)
   {
      ICommand command = ResolveCommand();

      if (command != null)
      {
         object eventArgs = null;
         object commandParameter = CommandParameter;

         if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EventArgsParameterPath))
         {
            eventArgs = GetEventArgsPropertyPathValue(parameter);
         }

         if (eventArgs == null && EventArgsConverter != null)
         {
            eventArgs = EventArgsConverter.Convert(parameter, typeof(object), EventArgsConverterParameter, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
         }

         if (eventArgs == null && PassEventArgsToCommand)
         {
            eventArgs = parameter;
         }

         if (command.CanExecute(commandParameter))
         {
            var compositeCommandParameter = new CompositeCommandParameter((EventArgs) eventArgs, commandParameter);
            command.Execute(compositeCommandParameter);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The only difference to the original code is that now an instance of `CompositeCommandParameter` will be created with the event arguments and the `CommandParameter` that is passed to your bound command.

Just for lazyness and easy setup, this would be the full command. As a side note, the `PassEventArgsToCommand` may no longer be needed, as they should always be passed now.

```
public sealed class CompositeInvokeCommandAction : TriggerAction<DependencyObject>
{
   private string commandName;

   public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CompositeInvokeCommandAction), null);
   public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(CompositeInvokeCommandAction), null);
   public static readonly DependencyProperty EventArgsConverterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EventArgsConverter", typeof(IValueConverter), typeof(CompositeInvokeCommandAction), new PropertyMetadata(null));
   public static readonly DependencyProperty EventArgsConverterParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EventArgsConverterParameter", typeof(object), typeof(CompositeInvokeCommandAction), new PropertyMetadata(null));
   public static readonly DependencyProperty EventArgsParameterPathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EventArgsParameterPath", typeof(string), typeof(CompositeInvokeCommandAction), new PropertyMetadata(null));

   /// <summary>
   /// Gets or sets the name of the command this action should invoke.
   /// </summary>
   /// <value>The name of the command this action should invoke.</value>
   /// <remarks>This property will be superseded by the Command property if both are set.</remarks>
   public string CommandName
   {
      get
      {
         ReadPreamble();
         return commandName;
      }
      set
      {
         if (CommandName != value)
         {
            WritePreamble();
            commandName = value;
            WritePostscript();
         }
      }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Gets or sets the command this action should invoke. This is a dependency property.
   /// </summary>
   /// <value>The command to execute.</value>
   /// <remarks>This property will take precedence over the CommandName property if both are set.</remarks>
   public ICommand Command
   {
      get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
      set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Gets or sets the command parameter. This is a dependency property.
   /// </summary>
   /// <value>The command parameter.</value>
   /// <remarks>This is the value passed to ICommand.CanExecute and ICommand.Execute.</remarks>
   public object CommandParameter
   {
      get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
      set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Gets or sets the IValueConverter that is used to convert the EventArgs passed to the Command as a parameter.
   /// </summary>
   /// <remarks>If the <see cref="Command"/> or <see cref="EventArgsParameterPath"/> properties are set, this property is ignored.</remarks>
   public IValueConverter EventArgsConverter
   {
      get { return (IValueConverter)GetValue(EventArgsConverterProperty); }
      set { SetValue(EventArgsConverterProperty, value); }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Gets or sets the parameter that is passed to the EventArgsConverter.
   /// </summary>
   public object EventArgsConverterParameter
   {
      get { return (object)GetValue(EventArgsConverterParameterProperty); }
      set { SetValue(EventArgsConverterParameterProperty, value); }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Gets or sets the parameter path used to extract a value from an <see cref= "EventArgs" /> property to pass to the Command as a parameter.
   /// </summary>
   /// <remarks>If the <see cref="Command"/> propert is set, this property is ignored.</remarks>
   public string EventArgsParameterPath
   {
      get { return (string)GetValue(EventArgsParameterPathProperty); }
      set { SetValue(EventArgsParameterPathProperty, value); }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Specifies whether the EventArgs of the event that triggered this action should be passed to the Command as a parameter.
   /// </summary>
   /// <remarks>If the <see cref="Command"/>, <see cref="EventArgsParameterPath"/>, or <see cref="EventArgsConverter"/> properties are set, this property is ignored.</remarks>
   public bool PassEventArgsToCommand { get; set; }

   /// <summary>
   /// Invokes the action.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="parameter">The parameter to the action. If the action does not require a parameter, the parameter may be set to a null reference.</param>
   protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
   {
      if (AssociatedObject != null)
      {
         ICommand command = ResolveCommand();

         if (command != null)
         {
            object eventArgs = null;
            object commandParameter = CommandParameter;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EventArgsParameterPath))
            {
               eventArgs = GetEventArgsPropertyPathValue(parameter);
            }

            if (eventArgs == null && EventArgsConverter != null)
            {
               eventArgs = EventArgsConverter.Convert(parameter, typeof(object), EventArgsConverterParameter, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            }

            if (eventArgs == null && PassEventArgsToCommand)
            {
               eventArgs = parameter;
            }

            if (command.CanExecute(commandParameter))
            {
               var compositeCommandParameter = new CompositeCommandParameter((EventArgs) eventArgs, commandParameter);
               command.Execute(compositeCommandParameter);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private object GetEventArgsPropertyPathValue(object parameter)
   {
      object commandParameter;
      object propertyValue = parameter;
      string[] propertyPathParts = EventArgsParameterPath.Split('.');
      foreach (string propertyPathPart in propertyPathParts)
      {
         PropertyInfo propInfo = propertyValue.GetType().GetProperty(propertyPathPart);
         propertyValue = propInfo.GetValue(propertyValue, null);
      }

      commandParameter = propertyValue;
      return commandParameter;
   }

   private ICommand ResolveCommand()
   {
      ICommand command = null;

      if (Command != null)
      {
         command = Command;
      }
      else if (AssociatedObject != null)
      {
         // todo jekelly 06/09/08: we could potentially cache some or all of this information if needed, updating when AssociatedObject changes
         Type associatedObjectType = AssociatedObject.GetType();
         PropertyInfo[] typeProperties = associatedObjectType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

         foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeProperties)
         {
            if (typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType))
            {
               if (string.Equals(propertyInfo.Name, CommandName, StringComparison.Ordinal))
               {
                  command = (ICommand)propertyInfo.GetValue(AssociatedObject, null);
               }
            }
         }
      }

      return command;
   }
}
```